# Authenticating Web Api using Azure B2C and MSAL in Xamarin Mobile App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

I am getting a **401 Unauthorized** message when I attempt to Authorize use of my Web Api from a Mobile App using MSAL.

Some names and App Id's have been changed to protect the innocent.
I'm aware this an exceedingly long post but I'm trying to provide as much info as possible to get a resolution.

Web App developed in ASP.NET core using Visual Studio 2017
Mobile App developed using Xamarin Forms and MSAL

The Web API address is:
https://mywebapi.azurewebsites.net

I am trying to hit:
https://mywebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/workdiary

I can sign in and out using my Mobile App via the Tenant: myTenant.onmicrosoft.com

> However once signed in I cannot use the cached Token obtained via
>   **AcquireTokenSilentAsync** to authorize a GET from my Web Api.

---

### **SOME CLUES TO WHERE THE PROBLEM MAY LIE:**

**Incorrect parameters in the HTTP request:**

-When I attempt to access my Web Api as follows-:

```
AuthenticationResult ar = await PCA.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(PCA.Users,PolicySignUpSignIn), Authority, false);
string token = ar.AccessToken;
var baseAddr = new Uri(ApiEndpoint);
var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddr };
var workDiaryUri = new Uri(baseAddr, "api/workdiary");
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, workDiaryUri);
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

... the response shows a Status of **401 Unauthorized**.

-The following static variables are set up-:

```
public static PublicClientApplication PCA = null;

// Azure AD B2C Coordinates
public static string Tenant = "myTenant.onmicrosoft.com";
public static string ClientID = "xyz456";
public static string PolicySignUpSignIn = "B2C_1_GeneralSignUpSignIn";
public static string[] Scopes = { "https://myTenant.onmicrosoft.com/api/mymobile.read.only" };
public static string ApiEndpoint = "https://mywebapi.azurewebsites.net";
public static string AuthorityBase = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Tenant}/";
public static string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicySignUpSignIn}";
public static UIParent UiParent = null;
```

-The PublicClientApplication is set up as follows-:

```
PCA = new PublicClientApplication(ClientID, Authority);
PCA.RedirectUri = $"msal{ClientID}://auth";
```

**what does work:**

The Mobile App Signs up and Signs in without a problem using the AcquireTokenAsync command.
However when trying to access the Web Api the token acquired from AcquireTokenSilentAsync appears not to Authorise the user.

-The App attempts to use a cached Token by using AcquireTokenSilentAsync in a try catch (this executes successfully)-:

```
AuthenticationResult ar = await PCA.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(PCA.Users, PolicySignUpSignIn), Authority, false);
```

-If no cached token is available the user performs the Sign Up Sign In process via button click (this also executes successfully)-:

```
AuthenticationResult ar = await PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(PCA.Users, PolicySignUpSignIn), UiParent);
```

---

**Incorrect Azure B2C Tenant setup for 'Sign-up or Sign-in' Policies:**

-In the Tentant I have 2 Applications set up-:

**My Mobile Frontend**

- which has Web App/Web Api set to NO
- and Native Client set to YES
- No Keys Added
- Api Access given to My Mobile API with a basic readonly permission
  scope    ***don't know if I need this (please advise)**
- No Published Scopes

(see figure NativeAppProperties1 & NativeAppProperties2)

[NativeAppProperties1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkPsG.jpg)

[NativeAppProperties2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EucJq.jpg)

AND

**My Mobile API**

- which has Web App/Web Api set to YES
- and Native Client set to NO
- 1 App Key added    ***don't know if I need this (please advise)**
- Api Access given to My Mobile API with a basic readonly permission
  scope    ***don't know if I need this (please advise)**
- 1 Scope Published (mymobile.read.only) Basic Permissions Only
  ***don't know if I need this (please advise)**

  (see figure WebApiProperties1 & WebApiProperties2 in the attached file)

[WebApiProperties1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRN0s.jpg)

[WebApiProperties2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JRvO.jpg)

-I also have a Sign-up or Sign-in Policy set up-:

**B2C_1_GeneralSignUpSignIn**

**- not sure if I need to add My Mobile API to Access Tokens (please
   advise)**

(see figure SignUpSignInProperties in the attached file)

[SignUpSignInProperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EvpT.jpg)

-For Identity Providers I only have Local Accounts- 'Email' set up-.

---

**Incorrect set up of the services in Web Api:**

When commenting out [Authorize] in my WebApi I can successfully run GET and POST requests both in local IIS testing and when published to Azure.
Adding in the [Authorize] command gives a 401 error as expected.

-appsettings.json file contains the following-:

```
"Authentication": {
    "AzureAd": {
      "Tenant": "myTenant.onmicrosoft.com",
      "ClientId": "abc123",
      "Policy": "B2C_1_GeneralSignUpSignIn"
    }
}
```

-Startup.Configure contains the following-:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();
```

-Startup.ConfigureServices is a a follows-:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 })
.AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.Audience = "abc123";
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
     };

     options.Authority = string.Format("myTenant.onmicrosoft.com/api", "B2C_1_GeneralSignUpSignIn");                      
     });


services.AddDbContext<WorkDiaryContext>(options =>
      options.UseInMemoryDatabase("WorkDiaryDB"));

services.AddMvc()
       .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Comment: Which ADAL version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much pain the answer has been revealed.

2 very minor changes:

The first was simply the dreaded slash.
The static variable for the ApiEndpoint in the Mobile App needs a slash at the end:

```
public static string ApiEndpoint = "https://mywebapi.azurewebsites.net/";
```

The second was one that between myself and Microsoft Support we were unable to find any clear documentation that outlines this required format none the less it is very specific.
The Authority option in the Startup.ConfigureServices of the Web Api should have the following format:

```
options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/myTenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_GeneralSignUpSignIn/v2.0/";
```

I hope this helps someone who may run into the same issue.